# Generating the Indicators without considering Saturday and Sunday

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have the data like below ,

```
Cus_Id  Name_Type   Call_Date   Day_Name    
------------------------------------------
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-02  Wednesday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-03  Thursday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-04  Friday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-05  Saturday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-06  Sunday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-07  Monday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-08  Tuesday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-09  Wednesday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-10  Thursday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-11  Friday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-12  Saturday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-13  Sunday
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-14  Monday
```

For the above the data I need to generate the indicator for every five days... means I need to separate every five days with out including the Saturday's and Sunday's

Example_Output_1:

```
Cus_Id  Name_Type   Call_Date   Day_Name   Required_Output  
---------------------------------------------------------------
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-02  Wednesday   1
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-03  Thursday    0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-04  Friday      0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-05  Saturday    0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-06  Sunday      0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-07  Monday      0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-08  Tuesday     0
```

Example_Output_2:

```
Cus_Id  Name_Type   Call_Date   Day_Name   Required_Output 
--------------------------------------------------------
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-10  Thursday    1
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-11  Friday      0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-12  Saturday    0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-13  Sunday      0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-14  Monday      0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-14  Tuesday     0
1074332 TAFW MIA    2020-12-14  Wednesday   0
```

I have tried with recursive CTE but I am unable to find the solution

```
;WITH CTE_Attnd AS
(
    SELECT 
         D.*, D.Call_Date AS Ref_Date
    FROM 
        #Tbl_Attnd D WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
        D.Rno = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        D.*,
        CASE 
           WHEN D.Call_Date > DATEADD(DAY,6,C.Ref_Date) 
              THEN D.Call_Date
              ELSE C.Ref_Date 
        END
    FROM 
        CTE_Attnd C
    JOIN 
        #Tbl_Attnd D WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.Cust_id = C.Cust_id
                                   AND D.IEX_Type = C.IEX_Type
                                   AND D.Rno = C.Rno+1
                                   --AND D.Day_Name <> 'Saturday'
                                   --AND D.Day_Name <> 'Sunday'
 )
 --SELECT *
 --FROM CTE_Attnd WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Can anyone please help with a SQL script?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: what is the logic for `Required_Output ` ?

Comment: I need to separate every customer for five days with out considering the Saturday and Sunday ....

Comment: You have `Required_Output` with value 1 or 0. What is the logic ?

Comment: For every five days set with out including Saturday and Sunday... the required_output should be 1 for the first record and for the rest of the four records it should be zero.